# Queue notification laravel 5.3 issue

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, queue, laravel-5.3

Well im testing this new notification stuff implemented in laravel 5.3 and its great,

i have this notification class which sends a mail to the authenticated user (when he hits a specific route) which is the default code.

**notification**

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class notifyme extends Notification  implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
```

This is the controller functions that instantiates the notification class

```
public function notifyme()
    {
        $user = Auth::user()

        $user->notify(new notifyme($user));
        //$user->notify((new notifyme($user))->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10)));

         return redirect('/home');
    }
```

now while using a ubuntu os , and setting my queue driver as sync which should work fine on localhost `QUEUE_DRIVER="sync"`

i started a worker `php artisan queue:work`

But nothing shows on the terminal windows also page still a bit slow (queues are not working)
[image]

i have the default queue.php and i didnt change it, and as i mentioned, im using sync as a driver
**Any suggested solution?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sync` driver doesn't use queues, it allows to run jobs synchronously for running tests for examle.

You need to use one of the driver provided by laravel listed here - [Laravel queues](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#introduction), or install some custom like RabbitMQ or something else

Comment: i just figure that out, i came to delete the answer, but you had a right answer, so thank you anyway (its working now using database)

Comment: I know this may be outdated, but i'm having same issue. whats the fix please? Do i need to create a job to handle sending the notifications? or do i just do 
`$user->notify((new DoctorCheckedIn($value))->delay($time));`

ps: `$time` is a carbon instance.